# Cannot write to local HDFS datanode

Tags: java, hadoop

I tried to write a file to my local HDFS setup using a java program I am using `Hadoop 2.3.0` distribution and `hadoop-client 2.3.0` `hadoop-hdfs 2.3.0` libraries.

In the HDFS log it shows the following error:

```
2014-04-07 18:40:44,479 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: prabhathp:50010:DataXceiver error processing unknown operation  src: /127.0.0.1:38572 dest: /127.0.0.1:50010
java.io.IOException: Version Mismatch (Expected: 28, Received: 26738 )
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.readOp(Receiver.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:198)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: I found the cause for this. I have used an incorrect hdfs url in the application.

Comment: please describe properly.. can't get

Answer (score 2):

If the error `Version Mismatch (Expected: 28, Received: 26738 )` is seen intermittently with a very high `Received`-Version, the cause can be that an application that does not use the hadoop rpc protocoll has connected to the datenode port.

We see this error for instance when somebody access the datanode url with a web browser (while intending to access the web-interface).

A misconfiguration can have similar effects.

Comment: I was using the port `50010` (the `dfsclient` port) instead of `50020` (the `ipc` port). this answer suggested me that I was using the port for the wrong service. quick reference for ports: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/

Answer (score 1):

The problem (for me) was an incorrect configuration of the properties `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` in the `hdfs-site.xml` file; they have to be URI and not just paths.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>/dfs/nn</value>  # wrong, change to 'file:///dfs/nn'
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>/dfs/dn</value>  # wrong, change to 'file:///dfs/dn'
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

java.io.IOException: Version Mismatch (Expected: 28, Received: 26738 )

Verison mismatch error indicates you are usng wrong hadoop jar. Ensure that the data.dir or name.dir has the correct VERSION file and you are using the correct hadoop version.

Run hadoop verison to confirm .